# Can you show me a good approach for taking the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-theorem

I tried to use binomial expansion, but I didn't get the same result.
I would like to know how to approach this please.
I know the answer is $\sqrt{e}$.

My problem is :

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

and also, can I find some good manipulation with this kind of problems ?

Comment: Welcome to math.se.  I recommend visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type equations using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax to make your equations more readable.

Comment: thanks for leting me know. was looking for something like that.

Comment: Your question title provides no indication of the question. You should change it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this way:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}&=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{1-\cos x}}\right)^{\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}=e^{\frac12}
\end{eqnarray}
This is because
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}=0,  \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{1-\cos x}=\infty, \lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac1x}=e,\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12. $$

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{1-\cos x}x=\frac x2+o(x)$$
hence
$$\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{1-\cos x}x\Bigr)^{\!\tfrac 1x}=\frac1x\ln\Bigl(1+\frac x2+o(x)\Bigr)=\frac1x\Bigl(\frac x2+o(x)\Bigr)=\frac12+o(1)$$
so that the limit is $\,\mathrm e^{1/2}$.

Comment: what 'o' means ? at o(x) ? how you got to

 $$\frac{x}{2} + o(x)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaaeaaaaaaaaa8
% qadaWcaaqaaiaadIhaaeaacaaIYaaaaiabgUcaRiaad+gapaGaaiik
% a8qacaWG4bWdaiaacMcaaaa!3C39!
$$

Comment: @idandi: it is the notion for rest of the terms in the Taylor polynomial

Comment: It is *Landau notation*: roughly speaking, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions  in a neighbourhood of $0$, and if $\,g(x)\ne 0$ (except at $x=0$), we say $f(x)=_0o(g(x)\,$ if $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. Here, intuitively, it means $o(x)$ tends to $0$ much faster than $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that we can write
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\exp(\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x})}{x}).
\end{equation*}
Applying L'Hopital's rule twice gives us 
\begin{equation*}
\exp(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+2x-\cos(x)+x\sin(x)}) \\
=\exp(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+2x-\cos(x)+x\sin(x)}).
\end{equation*}
Applying L'Hopital's rule again gives
\begin{equation*}
\exp(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2+x\cos(x)+2\sin(x)})=\sqrt{e}~_{\square} 
\end{equation*}

Comment: this looks so life changing , but i didnt learn this yet.
only next week.

Comment: I used a rule called L'Hopital's rule. if you have a quotient/fraction and taking the limit gives $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, then you can differentiate the numerator and the denominator and then take the limit. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: @George learning to use `\left` and `\right` will improve the parentheses in this answer, making it mor readable.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** look at the $\log$ then use $\cos{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)$ and $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$

Let's look in more details

$$\log\left(\left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\log\left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)$$

Using the expansion of $\cos$ we get

$$\log\left(\left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\log\left(1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x)\right)$$

And using the expansion of $\log$ we get

$$\log\left(\left(1+\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+o(x)$$

Comment: Nice (for the sake of simplicity, the first term expansion is enough here for the log, I believe -- this will make things easier in the proof).\

Comment: what 'o' means ? at o(x)  ?
i know log identities.  just dont know what this 'o' means

Comment: $f=o(g)\iff \lim\frac{f}{g}=0$

Comment: (actually, this is not exactly that as $g$ could techncially have zeros. It means there exists a function $\varepsilon$ going to $0$ such that $f=\varepsilon\cdot g$; but the definition @marwalix gives above is good enough for most purposes, and easier to parse.)